# load jquery plugin and jquery before html gets load

Tags: jquery

I have a problem ,I want to show responsive sliding image ,
 http://responsiveslides.com/

my code

```
$('document').ready(function () {


    $.getScript("sliding_zoom/responsiveslides.js", function () {

        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        maxwidth: 1024,
        speed: 2000,
        pause: false
    });


})

})
```

My HTML

```
           <ul class="rslides" id="Ul1">
                    <li>

                        <a href="Images/noimage.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" title="SHAKEOUT">


                            <img src="Images/Linear_Motion_Shakeout_1.jpg" alt="" />


                        </a>



                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Images/noimage.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" title="SHAKEOUT ">
                            <img src="Images/Shakeout.jpg" alt="" />



                        </a>

                    </li>


                </ul>
```

The code above is working fine ,but the problem is due to slow internet bandwidth or may be some problem .my ul li get loaded with all the image one by one (mean users are able to see all the images which is displayed in vertical direction for some time 6sec after the jquery plugin get fully load ul li with all image come to its normal position).

Comment: Load the script itself before the DOM is `ready`. Only perform the `responsiveSlides()` call on `ready`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function () {
```

Means execute when document is ready (page is completely loaded).

Put your code in `script` tag as very first element in `body`.

```
<body>
    <script>
         $.getScript("sliding_zoom/responsiveslides.js", function () {

           $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
            maxwidth: 1024,
           speed: 2000,
           pause: false
        });

    </script>
    <!-- Rest of the HTML -->
</body>
```

It will execute the code as soon as it is read.

Comment: did'nt get u ,could u provide me some example

Comment: But this would end calling `responseSlides()` before all slides actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

})
```

Correct way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code goes here 
});
```

This will run a script when the document structure is ready.